# Keras "acc" metrics - an algorithm

Tags: python-3.x, keras, neural-network

In Keras I often see people compile a model with mean square error function and "acc" as metrics.

```
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='mse',  metrics=['acc'])
```

I have been reading about acc and I can not find an algorithm for it?

2. What if I would change my loss function to binary crossentropy for an example and use 'acc' as metrics? Would this be the same metrics as in first case or Keras changes this acc based on loss function - so binary crossentropy in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the source code from [line 375](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/68dc181a5e34d1f20edabe531176b3bfb50001f9/keras/engine/training.py#L375). The metric_fn change dependent on loss function, so it is automatically handled by keras.

If you want to compare models using different loss function it could in some cases be necessary to specify what accuracy method you want to grade your model with, such that the models actually are tested with the same tests.

Comment: I don't see keras would give you 'mse' for 'acc'. I assume 'acc' manages only entropy loss functions automatically, for 'mse', 'mae' you need to specifiy correct metrics by yourself. Do you agree?

Comment: The metric will never change the loss function, but the type of loss-function (and output layer shape, see line 379) can change the type of metric function grading your model when 'acc' is used. Not sure if i fully understod you last question?

Comment: I checked the code you gave me and I have seen when metrics is 'acc', keras would automatically adopt acc for each of entropy loss functions. But if you have 'mse' or 'mae' for loss function and 'acc' for metrics, keras would use entropy metrics, not 'mse' or 'mae'. For these two or others, you need to specify your metrics.

Comment: Yes that seems right! I think accuracy make most sense when talking about classification. Using accuracy with classification, you want to measure how many of the classes was actually correctly classified. but when we have a regression problem, you probably dont want to score it based on the entropy metric? for regression you should probably specify the metric function such that you get the accuracy measure most desirable for your goal. Fun fact, metric does not have as strict restriction as loss function, so you can easily program your own designed for your case and goal.